# SQL Server: how to populate ID to table using an ID from another table?

Tags: sql-server

I have TaxTable with primary key taxid
the structure is as follow

```
taxid Type noteID
1     A
2     G
3     G
4     G
```

I also have a noteTable the table looks like this

```
NoteID SNoteText
456    Hellow joe
457    Non-Taxable
458    Non-Taxable
459    Non-Taxable
```

Now I need to populate taxType=G with noteID that Snotetext=Non-Taxable

so the end result will be like follow

```
taxid Type noteID
1     A    
2     G    457    
3     G    458    
4     G    459
```

- The order does not really matter, 457 can be in taxID 2 or 3 or 4. I mean there is no link between noteID 457 and TaxID 2 , it can be anywhere.
- The important key to know is that the total count of Snotetext="Non-Taxable" will always be the same as taxType=G. So in this example, there is 3 rows of TaxType=G and there is 3 rows of sNoteText="Non-Taxable" and this is important.

I hope that make sense. Thank you for the help

Comment: So why not just populate all noteID with 457? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: because this happens to have the same sNoteText now. but one day for example they want to update just the note for taxID 2 to "Taxable" without updating the rest of the taxID. does that make sense?

Comment: but if you are just randomly assigning the NoteID what does it matter? in other words why is 3=457 and not 459? Later on if you change only one of those it will affect a different record depending on what you assigned

Comment: Good point. in summary there are no link between taxID and NoteID. What I am doing is to create that link. So once I run the script. 2 is married to 457 forever and 3 is married to 458 forever. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a link between tables then create it. Something like this:

```
create table #taxTable(taxid int, [type] char(1),noteID int)
insert #taxTable(taxid,[type])
values (1,'A'),(2,'G'),(3,'G'),(4,'G'),
(5,'A'),(6,'G'),(7,'G'),(8,'G'),(9,'G')

create table #noteTable(NoteID int,SNoteText varchar(50))
insert #noteTable
values
(456,    'Hellow joe'),
(457    ,'Non-Taxable'),
(458    ,'Non-Taxable'),
(459    ,'Non-Taxable')

declare @cnt int
select @cnt=COUNT(noteid) from #noteTable where SNoteText='Non-Taxable'
-- It is possible to add 3rd CTE for cnt

;with n as (select row_number() over(order by noteID) rn,
noteId
from #noteTable where SNoteText='Non-Taxable'),
t as (select row_number() over(order by taxid) rn,
taxid,[type], noteid from #taxtable where [type]='G')
update t
set noteID = n.noteid
from  n inner join t on n.rn= (t.rn%@cnt)+1

select * from #taxtable
```